# How to enter username and password of the internet in ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu server on my PC.

I've got a modem and I connect my PC to the modem through a wired connection.

I connect to my PC from my laptop with `ssh`. it works, but when I wanna install something on my server it doesn't work.

My PC (my server) is connected to the modem through a wired connection and my modem needs a username and password to connect to the internet.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As written this can not be answered. What version of Ubuntu? You need to explain how the server needs a name and password to access internet.

Comment: ubuntu server 20.04. and 
for connecting to my internet, it needs to enter a username and password.

Comment: OK if it is a server then it does not use a username and password for that. What are you trying to do it still makes no sense.

Comment: when I try to ```sudo apt-get update``` it gets ```Check your Internet connection or proxy settings``` error.

Comment: Yes I get you are not connected to the internet what does not make sense is Ubuntu server does not use a username and password to access the internet it is a server. I think you are not telling all the info. Is the Ubuntu server running on top of Windows as a WSL?

Comment: no, I just installed an ubuntu server on my pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129663/discussion-between-hossein-safari-and-david).

Comment: If you connect directly to a modem (not through a router) then you may need to set up a PPPOE connection. See for example [2 Ways to Create PPPoE Connection in Ubuntu](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/create-pppoe-connection-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: When I don't have access to internet, how to install ```sudo apt install pppoeconf ```??